# Can I add featured image to a page (WordPress)

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming

I know, we can add a featured image to a *post* WordPress. But I want to know, can we also add a featured image to a *page*. If so, please share how.

Thanks Guys!

I have static page call 'homepage' in a template called 'HomePage Template'

This is the code for `HomePage-Template.php`

```
<?php
/*
 *  Template name: HomePage Template
 *  Description: Homepage Template use to create your home page as a default view.
 *
*/
?>
<?php get_header(); ?>

    <div class="grid-12">
        <?php//get page content and display ?>
        <?php if (have_posts()) : ?>
        <?php while (have_posts()) : the_post(); ?>
            <?//this will echo the page content ?>
            <?php the_content(''); ?>
        <?php endwhile; ?>
        <?php endif; ?>
    </div>

<?//php get_sidebar(); ?>

<?php get_footer(); ?>
```

**Primary Question:** Is there anything needed to activate or add a featured image option in the editor for *pages*?

Comment: below answer might work, it is working well to me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can get page thumbnail same as like post

```
<?php
/*
 *  Template name: HomePage Template
 *  Description: Homepage Template use to create your home page as a default view.
 *
*/
?>
<?php get_header(); ?>

    <div class="grid-12">
        <?php//get page content and display ?>
        <?php if (have_posts()) : ?>
        <?php while (have_posts()) : the_post(); ?>
            <?//this will echo the page content ?>
        <?php 
         if ( has_post_thumbnail() ) { // check if the post has a Post Thumbnail assigned to it.
         the_post_thumbnail();
         } 
         ?>
            <?php the_content(''); ?>
        <?php endwhile; ?>
        <?php endif; ?>
    </div>

<?//php get_sidebar(); ?>

<?php get_footer(); ?>
```

Comment: This is for get post thumbnail. I need to get page featured image. I like to know. How do I add featured image to a page in WP

Comment: hello @BigBroYesh you can get page featured image also in the same way, page and posts are have some features merely they are same, refer codex for more details http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/add_theme_support#Post_Thumbnails

Comment: Hi! Friend @Jothi Kannan, In my WP Theme no options for add featured image for pages as like post have. I mean, When we going to add post. There have option for add featured image. But how do I active that option for add page dashboard.

Comment: I will activated that handler for my template in function.php

Answer (score 3):

WordPress defaults to only having featured images "turned on" for posts.

To activate featured images for *pages*, simply add this line (to `functions.php` or elsewhere):

```
add_theme_support( 'post-thumbnails' );
```

That's it!

**Still not working?**
If you still don't see the featured-image meta box in the editor for pages, be sure to check the `Featured Image` checkbox in the `Screen Options` dropdown (top right tab in the editor when on a new/edit page/post screen).